How to count the number of visible rows in a Power BI table after applying filters?
I'm working in Power BI, and I have a table visual that displays rows based on various filters applied. I want to create a DAX measure that dynamically counts the number of visible rows in the table, considering all the filters currently applied.
I've tried different approaches, like using COUNTROWS with ALLSELECTED, DISTINCTCOUNT, and SUMMARIZE, but I haven't been able to get the correct result. Each approach either counts all rows in the data model or only returns a single row count.
Here's an example of what I tried:
DAX
    VisibleRowCount = COUNTROWS(VALUES(MyTable[Date]))

This measure still doesn't give the correct row count when filters are applied to the visual.
Could someone help me figure out the best way to count only the rows that are visible in the current context of a table visual?

Nov 12 added an image of the visual

Code fences are set up using backticks, not apostrophes. :-)

If you use a card visual to display the result, the filter should also apply on that visual . could you pls provide some sample data and expected output?

Filters applied directly to a Visual (ie via Filter Pane > Visual Filters) are only accessible or in affect in that visual. To count the number of rows in that visual, you need to determine which Dimension you are needing to count, as by design, visuals will summarize dimensions. Share a snip of your visual and the filter pane and we'll get a better idea of what you are working with.

you can add this count measure to the table visual to see what you will get. The table always apply aggregate functions on your data.
